# trying to access Azure storage from console app and get exception "Configuration system failed to initialize"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Trying to access Azure storage from console based app, I have following code but it throws when I try call CreateIfNotExist() on the blob container.

Any ideas why?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=superXXX;AccountKey=XXXX==");
            cloudBlobClient = new CloudBlobClient(account.BlobEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, account.Credentials);

            UploadBlob("folder", "file1.txt", "This is the contents");
        }
        catch (Exception exn)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(exn.Message);
        }
    }

    public static Uri UploadBlob(string path, string fileName, string content)
    {
        var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path);
        cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReference(fileName);
        blob.UploadText(content);
        return blob.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by an invalid app.config file, it had  element went it should not have - this was confusing the CLoudStroageAccount class.

More info here - http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2012/03/configuration-system-failed-to.html.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config file it is complaining about.  Take a look at:

http://blog.dampee.be/post/2011/03/31/Configuration-exception-when-migrating-a-ASPNET-application-to-a-Azure-webrole.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jongallant/archive/2008/03/02/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-one-possible-solution.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know you already found the answer to your problem, but for anyone else having this issue, I suddenly started getting this issue and **had not changed any config files** since my last commit when it was working.

I found the solution to my problem was to **right click each individual project in visual studio and click "Clean"**. You might need to just click "Clean" on the actual Azure Service project, but I did everything just to make sure. Doing "Clean Solution" wasn't working.

Now that I could debug it, I then had to **delete my deployment**, then **recreate it**. After doing this I was able to deploy successfully.